# No input file specified on nginx and php-cgi

Tags: windows, nginx, php-cgi

I'm trying to run nginx and php-cgi on my Windows PC, I've got up to the point where I want to move the html directory back two directory's so I can sort of create a structure.

The only problem I have now is that PHP doesn't pick up any .php file. I have tried loading a static html file (localhost/test.html) and it works fine but localhost/info.php doesn't work at all.

Can anyone give me some guidance on this? The part of the server block can be found below.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   ../../www;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a relative path in the `root` directive. Use the absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

php-cgi on Windows has a bug concerning relative paths apparently:

[[PHP-BUG] Bug #54955 [NEW]: FastCGI doesn't recognize Windows relative paths](http://grokbase.com/p/php/php-bugs/12c42xjyzd/bug-54955-com-fastcgi-doesnt-recognize-windows-relative-paths)

Your solutions are:

1. Absolute paths like what Michael Hampton said.
2. [Junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an NGINX stack on a local machine for development, there might be a preconfigured setting that is playing Gotcha:

```
open_basedir = "c:/webserver.;c:/”
```

[Here](http://www.sinaru.com/2015/04/05/fixing-no-input-file-specified-error-on-nginx-php/) is where I discovered the error on Windows with WinNMP:

> Today I wanted to try out Nginx server my windows machine. After setting up the basic server block details for my project, I called the site URL. In the WT-NMP stack to quickly setup the software I needed. In the server block, I needed to specify my root path in a different location other than WWW.
>
> Then when I hit the URL, I was getting “No Input File Specified” for my PHP script.
>
> Now I’m not much of a reader so I just goggled here and there and didn’t found much of a fix. So then I reviewed the php log files. There I got the error message as my project folder path is not within the allowed path(s): (c:/wt-nmp)
>
> So basically I had to edit php.init open_basedir value to include the path I stored my project. However here I could see that even the driver is considered to be as a path. So I ended up placing the driver letter since if I want to store more websites in my ‘d’ drive, I would not encounter this error.  This is the final line. I have bold my text to indicate the change I made.
>
> open_basedir = “c:/wt-nmp.;d:/”
>
> “Happy Nginx, is a good Nginx.”

Comment: Thanks. It was `open_basedir`